# Open Private Instance of Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Outlook VBA macro project which is very important to be fast as it will be used many times a day. If it's too slow - for example taking 10-15 seconds to execute, many users simply won't use it.

My code makes heavy use of a single Excel workbook. Opening the workbook takes somewhere between 1 and 8 seconds on testing (I'm not sure why the discrepancy... - if there are any suggestions of speeding this up that would be awesome but beside the point of what I'm trying to achieve with this post).

Because it takes so long to open, I'd one of the strategies I'm using to make it fast is to hold an Excel workbook open in the background. That way, the workbook is opened once on Outlook start up and then kept open. My macro functions don't have to open and close it each time - meaning they are almost instantaneously fast. The workbook is invisible and has all the usual speed up adjustments (`enableEvents = false, screenUpdatingFalse, displayStatusBar = false, displayAlters = false, and xlCalculationManual`). So far so good.

The problem comes when the user opens up an Excel document and Windows grabs my instance of Excel. Obviously with all the speed up settings, this does not go well.

I can enable and disable the speed up settings on each macro - this will allow the user to open a new Excel window. Better but suddenly my hidden workbook appears. This will confuse the user - not a great outcome either.

[This solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/can-i-create-an-instance-of-excel-that-can-only-be/98d1ef9d-76aa-43cf-bf7b-6324fcb19018?page=1) appears to work but seems quite dangerous. It sets `.IgnoreRemoteRequests` to false - which will then be written the registry on closing the Excel instance if not prevented. This would mean then mean that the user's Excel would never open (WTF Microsoft!?). It can be prevented by setting the `.IgnoreRemoteRequests` back to `True`, however, the only way to make sure that it's robust is to put it in the workbook itself - which would require it to be macro enabled.

I don't want my workbook to be macro enabled because of the security settings set by admin. It is imperative that the workbook remains an XLSX file.

From searching, it appears that it is possible to change the registry settings to enable a private instance of outlook. However, I don't have admin privileges, and I'm limited to Outlook macros. So this option is not available.

Is there a way to have a private instance of Excel created by Outlook without making that workbook macro enabled? Failing that, is there a way to keep my workbook hidden from users when my instance of Excel is used?

If all of the above is impossible, is there a way to speed up the process of opening my workbook? As I mentioned above, in my testing, the time it takes to open is either about one second or about eight seconds. I have no idea why it's so quick sometimes and so slow at other times.

Edit: I slightly modified @FaneDuru's code below will reproduce the behaviour for me:

```
Sub testCreateExcelNewSession()
  Dim objExcel As Object, wb As Object, wbPath As String
  Dim ws as Object
  wbPath = "[redacted]\users\[redacted]\home\documents\dataRegisterV0.2.xlsx"

  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  
  With objExcel
    .Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = .Workbooks.Open (wbPath)
```

'<Break point here!!> --> This is where I test to see if I can open a random other excel document.
' When I do this test, the hidden workbook appears.

```
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

  End With

  Set wb = Nothing: Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

I run the code above, hit the breakpoint, then open an excel document - then the hidden workbook appears.

Comment: If you are creating a new invisible instance of Excel , the user shouldn't be interacting with it anyway.

Comment: Do you *have* to use an Excel Workbook? Is it data lookup or are you using worksheet functions, storing data in it?
Have you tried "connecting" to the workbook using ODBC rather than "opening" it?

Comment: @Rory is correct - I've just run a trial and a new instance of Excel is created in the "UI" - my test "invisible" workbook is still not visible to the User, nor is it closed when I close my 2nd visible workbook.  Are you running a really old version of Windows/Office? This grabbing of existing instances used to happen years ago

Comment: @Rory If you create the invisible instance (which is what I'm doing), then open a new workbook, the invisible instance will be used and set to visible. The hidden workbook is then suddenly visible.

Comment: What Excel/Office version do you use? This shouldn't happen... Please, edit your question and show the code you use for creating of this hidden session.

Comment: @CHill60 I haven't tried connecting to a workbook but I figured it probably wouldn't work. My workbook is stored in a document management system - not Sharepoint or locally.

Comment: @FaneDuru I'll check tomorrow when I'm back at my computer. But I thought it was pretty standard behaviour of Excel to use any current instance of Excel to open a workbook rather than open a new one every time. I don't see how it being created by Vba matters to this behaviour.

Comment: It is not a matter of opening **a new session every time**! It is a matter of opening **only a new visible session**, if a hidden one exists... Then, what do you mean by "My workbook is stored in a document management system"? Please, try be more specific. Give us a full name of such a workbook, please.

Comment: .@FaneDuru my document is a normal xlsx stored in Content Manager version 10 (I think). It used to be called Trim.

Comment: Can you show us a full name of such a workbook from this Content Manager. Your problem may be related to using such a "document management system". If so, can you save the respective workbook locally? Then, you should open it from its local location and it must behave as you need.

Comment: What do you need the excel file for in the first place? And if you need it and as you do not do any calculations in it why don't you access it via another method lilke ADODB. Anyway, sounds like an xy-Problem. So, question remains: What's the real issue?

Comment: @FaneDuru to access the workbook, my macro performs the following steps: 1. Open Content Manager. 2. Download the workbook from Content Manager. 3. Open the local file like a normal excel. So the file path is a regular Windows file path - ie "\documents\temp\my excel.xlsx".

Comment: @Storax I am not across ADODB connections to Excel documents, SQL databases or the like. I am very restricted by the software available on my work network - can I create an ADODB connection to a local excel file to add/remove/change data with only what's available in regular MS Office and VBA? I don't have MS Access or other db software installed.  I cannot download other Com addins either.

Comment: Also I'm using MS Office 16.0.

Comment: @user1357607: MS Access is not needed, but of course, the ADODB library is required, which depends on your installation. You can check that by having a look at Tool/References and looking for `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library`(x.x. = version). If you find it, you have it in your installation. Otherwise, you are out of luck. And yes, it is possible to add/remove/change data as long as you have it in a proper form like a table

Comment: @user1357607: Question remains: What do you need an excel file in the first place for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256456/discussion-between-user1357607-and-storax).

Comment: Actually chat is blocked for me. @Storax My macro saves emails and attachments to Content Manager, and then stores relevant information, including user inputted data in hidden tables in the Excel workbook. The workbook then has Power Pivot tables to show relevant information back to the user. It's important that the workbook remains XLSX and that the users only see the pivot tables which they can interact with to see the data they want. From my quick googling, it seems that creating an ADODB connection to the XLSX will work and is quicker than opening a full instance of Excel.

Comment: If you need a Power Pivot table that the user can interact with, you’re out of luck. This functionality is difficult to rebuild with ADODB alone.

Answer (score 1):

As (correctly) stated in the first comment, a new workbook will **not be open in the hidden session (making it visible)**. You do not show the way you create the hidden Excel session. Anyhow, using the next (simple) code, it creates a new hidden session, which (theoretically) will not be used by a new workbook to open in it.

A new workbook should be opening in a **new session**. Now, the problem becomes to identify the hidden session between the two (or more) sessions...

1. Please, try using the next code to create the new hidden session and open the necessary workbook:

```
Sub testCreateExcelNewSession()
  Dim objExcel As Object, wb As Object, wbPath As String
  
  wbPath = "C:\your excel workbook full name"
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  
  With objExcel
    .Visible = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Workbooks.Open (wbPath)
  End With
  Set wb = Nothing: Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

2. Open a new workbook (any workbook) and see it in a new visible session. If not, this can be (only) related to that Content Manager you use. I suppose, that you are able to save the respective workbook locally. If so, please do it (programmatically) and open it again for the local path. It now should behave as you need.
3. Now, identify the hidden session using such a simple code:

```
Sub getHiddenExcelSession()
   Dim objExcel As Object, wb As Object, wbPath As String
   
   wbPath = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\export.XLSX"
   Set objExcel = GetObject(wbPath).Application
   Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks(1)
   Debug.Print objExcel.hwnd, wb.Name

   Set objExcel = Nothing, Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I did not explicitly set visible to false - as the Excel session was hidden without doing that. I'll check if expressly setting it to false ensures it remains hidden when I log back in tomorrow.

Comment: I have now confirmed that this does not work in the manner I previously described. That is that it fails following these specific steps: 1. All excel instances are closed (I checked Task manager to make sure). 2. Run the VBA code above to create a hidden Excel instance. 3. Open a random Excel workbook from my documents folder. After opening any random workbook, my hidden workbook appears and the instance listed in Task Manager moves from Background Processes to Apps. Also, as per my other comment, I'm running Outlook and Excel 16.0.

Comment: I see an admin has closed the question. I don't see why - the code in this answer reproduces the problem. I even implemented it in an new OTM file (I made a copy of mine elsewhere so as not to lose it). The issue is nothing to do with Content Manager - as from the perspective of Excel, it's opened from a local file - and it's reproduced using the code above. The issue remains.

The reason I mentioned Content Manager was because in answer to a different comment from @CHill60 regarding ODBC, I incorrectly assumed that was some connection to One Drive or Sharepoint.

Comment: @user1357607 Not "an admin" closed your question... There must be three users having a notoriety level voting to close it. And selecting an option as closing reason. Can't you see the three users and also the reason (`needs debugging details`)? Your problem cannot be reproduced! **All our installations behave different than yours**. But, forget about it right now. Usually, so is happens with a question not showing the problematic code. I also asked you to show the code you use... Now, don't you have Office installed at home? Did you try my above suggested solution on your personal system?

Comment: @user1357607 Does your home installation behave as the one at your office? If not, it may be an installation problem. But you must check this as I suggested (testing on a different environment). Now, what's happening if you **firstly** manually or programmatically open a workbook and **after that** your code tries creating the hidden Excel session? Does it become visible? I have some doubts, but I never heard about the behavior you describe, neither... So, how does it behave? When open a third workbook, does it make the hidden session to be shown? I don't think so, but who knows...?

Comment: Unfortunately my home set up is a Mac - so no luck testing it at home. I did find this from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance which, although doesn't mention hidden workbooks does say the default behaviour is to use one instance of Excel to open all workbooks. So from this, I would expect that the behaviour I'm experiencing is actually the correct behaviour. Have you actually tested the code in the exact manner I said? If so, do you get one or two instances of Excel in your task manager?

Comment: @user1357607 I am afraid that the linked page **treats only VISIBLE instances**. This is the normal behavior for **a visible instance/session**. The hidden instances **must be/remain hidden**. This is what hidden mean... And using a break point or opening another workbook after the creating instance code finished is **strictly the same**. I did that many, many times. I know enumerating the existing Excel instances (hidden or not). Did you try what I suggested above (**to firstly open a workbook** and **after that** creating the hidden instance)? Another workbook should be open in the visible.

Comment: @user1357607 The behavior you are talking about was the default one **before 2013**. After Office 2013 the normal behavior is **to not open the new workbook in the hidden instance**. It is good to understand why this behavior in your company installation. But, is the same behavior in all company computer? Did you check it, at least, for 4, 5 cases?